# Distinct IDs from one table for inner join SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to take the distinct IDs that appear in table a, filter table b for only these distinct IDs from table a, and present the remaining columns from b. I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        a.ID,
        a.test_group,
        b.ch_name,
        b.donation_amt

    FROM table_a a 
        INNER JOIN table_b b 
        ON a.ID=b.ID
    ORDER by a.ID;
) t
```

This doesn't seem to work. This query worked:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.test_group, b.ch_name, b.donation_amt
FROM table_a a
    inner join table_b b
    on a.ID = b.ID
order by a.ID
```

But I'm not entirely sure this is the correct way to go about it. Is this second query only going to take unique combinations of a.ID and a.test_group or does it know to only take distinct values of a.ID which is what I want.

Comment: Can you post a sample of rows from the tables together with a sample of what you expect the query output to be? My instinct is that your query is already correct though. Your two queries are functionally the same - the outer SELECT * does not change anything but it would have failed because it has a `;` inside the `()` where not allowed. Remember that `DISTINCT` acts on the full rowset returned by a query rather than on any single column.

Comment: What do you mean "This doesn't seem to work"?  Do you get an error?  Or the wrong data or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first and second query are similar.(just that you can not use `;` inside your query) Both will produce the same result.

Even your second query which you think is giving you desired output, can not produce the output what you actually want.

`Distinct` works on the entire column list of the `select` clause.

In your case, if for the same `a.id` there is different `a.test_group` available then it will have multiple records with same `a.id` and different `a.test_group`.

Comment: I should have been clear, the `a.test_group` does not vary for a given `a.ID`

Comment: Then you will get the distinct data for a.id, a.test_group and if there multiple record in the table b with different b.ch_name, b.donation_amt then your final result will have multiple a.id with different value of table b columns. Else distinct.